# How does facebook manage image uploads?

Tags: file, web-applications, social-networking

How does facebook manage the storage of images uploaded by their members?  I would imagine the files are divided across multiple storage devices, but how should the decision be made to determine which file system to add the file to, if there is a table that holds all of the paths to the respective storage devices?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's photo storage system is called Haystack.

Here's a technical introduction: http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919

Note that the link is from 2009, so some of the numbers are probably wildly out of date by now.